# Is there a short expression giving $135791113\cdots 2017201920212023$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I created the following number

$$135791113\cdots 2017201920212023$$ which emerges by writing down the odd numbers from $1$ to $2023$ in increasing order. Its full decimal expansion can be seen [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004282444883). As factordb shows (and PARI/GP approves) , this number is composite , but it has no small prime factor.

I searched prime factors with PARI/GP and the online magma calculator and also with Alpertron. They all seem too slow, so I think I have to use yafu (or GMP ECM)

Unfortunately, I have only yafu versions that cannot handle long expressions (possibly because of my old computer / system) . Therefore my question :

> Is there a short expression giving this number ?

It should contain only the fundamental operators +-./^ and quite small numbers.
Using the structure I could compress the number to about the half , but it is still too long.

If wished, I can post this expression, but I do not think that it is actually helpful.

If someone has access to an efficient tool , prime factors of this number are appreciated.

Comment: @Martin Hopf Here you have a number you can try to factor.

Comment: @hardmath Here you have a number you can try to factor.

Comment: You know how to sum an arithmetic progression times a geometric one, don't you?

Comment: Would it be helpful to represent the number as a sum of $4$ arithmetico-geometric series, where one is $13579000\ldots$, one contains the $2$-digit odd numbers, one contains the $3$-digit odd numbers, and one contains the $4$-digit odd numbers? Or the expression has to be much shorter?

Comment: @peterwhy The same as what I'm saying. Takes one line in LaTeX after the summation, so I doubt you can do a much shorter one :-)

Comment: Found a [26-digit factor](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004282444883).

Comment: @MartinHopf Chances are good that it is the smallest prime factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it as $$13579\cdot 10^{3488}+10^{3398}\sum_{k=0}^{44} (11+2k)10^{2(44-k)}+10^{2048}\sum_{k=0}^{449}(101+2k)10^{3(449-k)}+\sum_{k=0}^{511}(1001+2 k)10^{4(511-k)}$$

or equivalently

$$13579\cdot 10^{3488}+10^{3398}\frac{1091\cdot 10^{90}-10001}{9801}+10^{2048}\frac{100901\cdot 10^{1350}-1000001}{998001}+\frac{10009001\cdot 10^{2048}-20247977}{99980001}$$

but I doubt those expressions turn out to be useful to investigate the factors of the number.

Comment: That's a great expression, all respect!